# Where is minDate on membership start date set? Or can I change what minDate is set to?

Tags: civimember

So we have historic records which have been imported which include start dates going back to 1990s.

However, when those records are brought up for editing, the minDate kicks in and sets the date to 20 years ago.

I would like to be able disable the minDate test altogether, but cannot find it in the form setups at all.

If I can't disable it, can I set it to something much older?

Any suggestions as to where I should be looking, can't find anything in membership.php or .tpl that seems to set this.

Answer (score 3):

minDate for these entities can be updated at `Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Date Preferences`, i.e, `civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/date?action=reset=1`

[image]

Click on `Edit` and update the Start Offset(minDate) to eg 30. This will default the membership start date to start from current year - 30.

[image]

Comment: Of course it is!!!  Thanks